# class inheritance java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have a main class where the user enters data, after I would like to go to another class. I do not know how to go to next class and inherit values x and y in java code.

```
public class main {
                     int x=25;
                     int y =25;
                   //Go to next class second
                  }

public class second {
                     //inherit values of x and y
                     //manipulate values 
                     //Go to next class third
                    }

public class third {
                     //inherit values of x and y from second class
                     //manipulate values 
                   }
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Main {
                     int x=25;
                     int y =25;
                   //Go to next class second
                   aMethod(){
                    Second s = new Second();
                    s.manipulateValues(x,y);
                    }
                  }

public class Second {
                     //inherit values of x and y
                     //manipulate values 
                     //Go to next class third
                       public void manipulateValues(int x, int y){
                           //manipulate here  
                           Third t = new Third ();
                           s.manipulateHereToo(x,y);
                       }
                    }

public class Third {
                     //inherit values of x and y from second class
                     //manipulate values 
                      public void manipulateHereToo(int x, int y){
                             //manipulate again
                       }
                   }
```

So you are not obligated to use inheritance.

Comment: from the main class how do I go to the second class, once the user has entered values?

Comment: You create an instance of type Second, and call the method you are interested in, passing the two arguments (x and y).

Answer (score 3):

The problem you described has nothing to do with inheritance.
The solution appears to be a two step process.

1. [Learn Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).
2. Pass the desired values as parameters to method calls.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you mean inheritance here.  Are you just trying to pass these values do other classes to perform calculations on them?

If you do actually mean inheritance, to build off another answer already given, you might want to modify it like this.

```
public class second extends main{
                     //inherit values of x and y
                     //manipulate values 
                     //Go to next class third
                    }

public class third extends second{
                     //inherit values of x and y from second class
                     //manipulate values 
                   }
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to pass the values of x and y

Answer (score 0):

```
public class second extends main{
                     //inherit values of x and y
                     //manipulate values 
                     //Go to next class third
                    }

public class third extends main{
                     //inherit values of x and y from second class
                     //manipulate values 
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from another class by using the `extends` keyword.

```
public class First {
    int x = 25;
    int y = 25;
}
//Class Second inherits (extends) from class First.
//This class will inherit from First, all its values (x and y).
public class Second extends First {
    public Second() {
        //Here we change the values of x and y in Second's constructor.
        x = 26;
        y = 26;
    }
}
```

Comment: from the main class how do I go to the second class, once the user has entered values?

Comment: @Simon What do you mean "go to"?